# How do I use MySQL Left Join to order by the column of another table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I am building a custom forum in CodeIgniter and currently working to order the threads of a board by the time that the last message of the thread was posted.  I have a table for categories(parents), boards(children), threads, and messages(thread replies).  What I want to do is to get all the threads in the current board and order them by the time of the thread's last message(last_msg_id).

I thought I had the query written correctly, however, I am getting an SQL error.  Maybe my logic is just incorrect.  What do you guys think?

This is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT 
                    t.child_id, t.thread_id, t.last_msg_id,
                    m.thread_id, m.message_id, m.date_posted
                    FROM forum_threads AS t 
                    LEFT JOIN forum_messages ON m.message_id = t.last_msg_id AS m
                    WHERE t.child_id = " . $board_id . "
                    ORDER BY m.date_posted DESC
                    LIMIT 10";
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS m WHERE t.child_id = 1 ORDER BY m.date_posted DESC ' at line 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as m` is in the wrong place:

```
SELECT t.child_id, t.thread_id, t.last_msg_id, m.thread_id, m.message_id, m.date_posted
FROM forum_threads AS t
LEFT JOIN forum_messages AS m ON m.message_id = t.last_msg_id
WHERE t.child_id =  ".$board_id."
ORDER BY m.date_posted DESC 
LIMIT 10
```